# `uninitialized constant Sidekiq::Rails::Reloader` after upgrading to Rails 5.0.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq

I just upgraded from Rails 4.2.6 to Rails 5.0.0.1. I have the following configuration for Sidekiq UI in `config/routes.rb`:

```
if Rails.application.queuing_enabled?
  require 'sidekiq/web'
  Sidekiq::Web.set :session_secret, Rails.application.secrets[:secret_key_base]

  authenticate :user, ->(u) { u.admin? } do
    mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
  end
end
```

The value of `Rails.application.queuing_enabled?` will always be `true` in `production` mode, but `false` in `development` and `test`.

After upgrading, I am facing the below error when I run anything on my local (tried running `rspec`, `rails middleware` etc.):

```
rails aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Sidekiq::Rails::Reloader
/home/project/config/routes.rb:66:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/project/config/routes.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/home/project/config/environment.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/home/project/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/home/project/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/project/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => middleware => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

My `Gemfile.lock` has the following versioning info for Sidekiq.

```
sidekiq (4.2.7)
  concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
  connection_pool (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.0)
  rack-protection (>= 1.5.0)
  redis (~> 3.2, >= 3.2.1)
sidekiq-limit_fetch (3.4.0)
  sidekiq (>= 4)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this was a bug with Sidekiq 4.2.7, which will be resolved in the next release.

Please see https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/3275 for more details.